# Invalid address id at add to cart

Tags: magento2

I have getting error
Invalid address id at add to cart , issue with only migration customer

Any solution to resolve this issue

https://prnt.sc/7zG0P0KEeHRW

Comment: What version of Magento are you running?

Comment: What do you mean by it only affects migrated customers? Take a look at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/196101/magento-2-invalid-address-id-when-adding-product-to-cart ... you may need to write a SQL script to delete all the address id for the migrated customer since they don't exist in the current magento

Comment: Magetno version is 2.3.3-p1

Comment: Have you any SQL script to delete all the address of migrated customer ?

Comment: try something like ``select * from customer_entity where `default_shipping` not in (select entity_id from customer_address_entity)`` for both default_shipping and default_billing. Once you validate that the result is what you want to fixed then change the sql to ``update customer_entity set default_shipping = null where `default_shipping` not in (select entity_id from customer_address_entity)``

Comment: Also, since you are running an older version of Magento, you may need to add code to prevent this issue from happening in the future.